# how to merge multipath in one single path to create a Graph

Tags: matlab, networking

I have this multipath:

```
[4876,12282,19222]
[4876,12282,19240]
[4876,12282,19254]
[4876,12282,19681]
[4876,12282,20222]
[4876,12282,20347]
[4876,12282,2401,159]
[4876,12282,2401,14174]
[4876,12282,2401,18407]
[4876,12282,14691,7865]
[4876,12282,7318,10314]
[4876,12282,17452,12152]
[4876,12282,14917,794]
[4876,12282,2401,9463]
[4876,12282,2401,18576]
[4876,12282,14691,7865,9496]
[4876,12282,14691,3722]
[4876,12282,14691,4216]
```

I want to merge them in a single path with keeping the edges incident order to create a graph. I am a pretty new in Graph and Network Algorithms area. any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `sparse` to create an adjacency matrix:

```
mp{1} = [4876,12282,19222];
mp{2} = [4876,12282,19240];
mp{3} = [4876,12282,19254];
mp{4} = [4876,12282,19681];
mp{5} = [4876,12282,20222];
mp{6} = [4876,12282,20347];
mp{7} = [4876,12282,2401,159];
mp{8} = [4876,12282,2401,14174];
mp{9} = [4876,12282,2401,18407];
mp{10} = [4876,12282,14691,7865];
mp{11} = [4876,12282,7318,10314];
mp{12} = [4876,12282,17452,12152];
mp{13} = [4876,12282,14917,794];
mp{14} = [4876,12282,2401,9463];
mp{15} = [4876,12282,2401,18576];
mp{16} = [4876,12282,14691,7865,9496];
mp{17} = [4876,12282,14691,3722];
mp{18} = [4876,12282,14691,4216];
% get all connections
idx1 = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) x(1:end-1),mp,'UniformOutput',0));
idx2 = cell2mat(cellfun(@(x) x(2:end),mp,'UniformOutput',0));
% remove duplicates
idxs = unique([idx1(:),idx2(:)],'rows');
% get max element index
maxIdx = max(idxs(:));
% create adjacency matrix and undirected graph
A = sparse( idxs(:,1),idxs(:,2),ones(size(idxs,1),1),maxIdx,maxIdx );
G = graph(A | A');
```

Comment: Thank you @user2999345  I used the first part of your answer and I managed how to create the graph really appreciate your cooperation